# Why am I am getting distorted UI in Google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am facing this problem for weeks now while completing the ACE Google cloud edu. While creating buckets or clusters the windows opens up distorted. Even some options are not showing at all. My pc display runs well in other websites but problem arises when I am in GCP. If anyoneenter image description here know a solution to fix this, please let me know. I am trying to fix this for a long time but couldn't.

Comment: 1. Can you try [supported browsers](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/console#supported_browsers) of GCP console, and also try to [Clear the cookies and cache](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-look-wrong-or-appear-differently). 

2. Try another device or your mobile device then browse the GCP console, if same behavior

Answer (score 0):

Tried to open the GUI of BigQuery on my Chrome browser and I'm seeing a display, what you can do is to try clear cache on your browser.

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More More.
3. Click **More tools** and then **Clear browsing data.**
4. At the top, choose a time range. To delete everything, select **All time.**
5. Next to "Cookies and other site data" and "Cached images and files," check the boxes.
6. Click **Clear data.**

Another is try to use incognito from your browser.

Also open your browsers debugger and then refresh the page and post the error message on your post.